# Oh-My-ZSH Command ... Takes You Back One Directory - How do you stop this?

Tags: bash, zsh

I have Oh-My-ZSH and in bash I can create and CD into a directory called `...` however with zsh I cannot, instead it is taking me back one directory. Does anybody know where this configuration actually sits in the `~/.oh-my-zsh` directory - I was unable to find it and that functionality is annoying me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi pal ! Why tag bash here? You may edit the question

Comment: Maybe try `cd "..."`?

Comment: Hey ForceBru, adding the quotes did work but I was also curious if it was possible to remove the subcommand rewrite on the ``...`` string. Thansk!